# I need to change css button hover color

Tags: css

i've tried all of the top resolutions here, but so far have only been able to change the highlight color behind the button text and not the entire button. i'm trying to change the hover state color to a yellow hex on a youcanbook.me calendar, but only have access to css updater, not the source code... any thoughts? edit: developer's code for new themes is here --> youcanbook.me/design_guidelines

```
.gridPage .gridDays .gridDay div.gridNoFree:not(.gridTechnicallyFree):not(.gridHighlight) {
    display: none;
}

div.showTechnicallyFree div.gridTechnicallyFree {
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #444;
}

div.gridHighlight {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.gridBusy {
    display: none !important;
}

div.gridTechnicallyFree {
    display: none !important;
}

.gridPage .gridDays .gridDay div.gridNoFree {
    display: none;
}

.gridPage .gridDays div.dayNoFree {
    display: none;
}

div.gridHighlight {
    background-color: #ffdf00
}

div.gridSlot:not(.gridBusy):hover {
    background-color: #ffd700;
}
```

Comment: We can't tell what button you're talking about without some relevant HTML. Even though you can't edit the HTML, it would be very helpful to include at least the relevant portion. Otherwise these styles really tell us nothing.

Comment: Often times to override styles that you cannot edit directly, the best thing to do is do the **SAME** style, change the rule to what you want, and add `!important` to that rule.

Comment: @scoopzilla !imporant is bad practice and should be avoided where possible. It's often a matter of css specifity. Harry Roberts' talks helped me a lot to understand css better, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OKZOV-iLj4

Comment: @wmk, I don't disagree. However, the OP stated that they cannot change the base style sheet. `!important` would do that in this case. Perhaps the OP could make a new rule and edit the main source?

Comment: thanks guys. yeah i understand it's difficult to know. here is a page with downloads of the base/base form css, if it helps https://youcanbook.me/design_guidelines/